# FFMProbe Output on Android

Tags: android, android-ffmpeg

How to execute and get the output of the FFMProbe command on FFMPegKit? I tried various ways. But I failed. Can anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few days later I got success (though the Question and answer time is same. But I tried it earlier more).

```
FFprobeKit.executeAsync("-v error -show_streams -print_format json videopath") { session ->
        Log.d("TAG", "fileDetails: FMProbe output: ${session?.output}")
    }
```

This Log.d print the details of inputted video as a JSON (as the command).

```
FFMProbe output: {
    "streams": [
        {
            "index": 0,
            "codec_name": "h264",
            "codec_long_name": "unknown",
            "profile": "100",
            "codec_type": "video",
            "codec_time_base": "1/60",
            "codec_tag_string": "avc1",
            "codec_tag": "0x31637661",
            "width": 1920,
            "height": 1080,
            "coded_width": 1920,
            "coded_height": 1088,
            "closed_captions": 0,
            "has_b_frames": 1,
            "sample_aspect_ratio": "1:1",
            "display_aspect_ratio": "16:9",
            "pix_fmt": "yuv420p",
            "level": 40,
            "color_range": "tv",
            "color_space": "bt709",
            "color_transfer": "bt709",
            "color_primaries": "bt709",
            "chroma_location": "left",
            "refs": 1,
            "is_avc": "true",
            "nal_length_size": "4",
            "r_frame_rate": "30/1",
            "avg_frame_rate": "30/1",
            "time_base": "1/15360",
            "start_pts": 0,
            "start_time": "0.000000",
            "duration_ts": 3329024,
            "duration": "216.733333",
            "bit_rate": "1461827",
            "bits_per_raw_sample": "8",
            "nb_frames": "6502",
            "disposition": {
                "default": 1,
                "dub": 0,
                "original": 0,
                "comment": 0,
                "lyrics": 0,
                "karaoke": 0,
                "forced": 0,
                "hearing_impaired": 0,
                "visual_impaired": 0,
                "clean_effects": 0,
                "attached_pic": 0,
                "timed_thumbnails": 0
            },
            "tags": {
                "language": "und",
                "handler_name": "ISO Media file produced by Google Inc.",
                "vendor_id": "[0][0][0][0]"
            }
        },
        {
            "index": 1,
            "codec_name": "aac",
            "codec_long_name": "unknown",
            "profile": "1",
            "codec_type": "audio",
            "codec_time_base": "1/44100",
            "codec_tag_string": "mp4a",
            "codec_tag": "0x6134706d",
            "sample_fmt": "fltp",
            "sample_rate": "44100",
            "channels": 2,
            "channel_layout": "stereo",
            "bits_per_sample": 0,
            "r_frame_rate": "0/0",
            "avg_frame_rate": "0/0",
            "time_base": "1/44100",
            "start_pts": 0,
            "start_time": "0.000000",
            "duration_ts": 9561088,
            "duration": "216.804717",
            "bit_rate": "127999",
            "max_bit_rate": "127999",
            "nb_frames": "9337",
            "disposition": {
                "default": 1,
                "dub": 0,
                "original": 0,
                "comment": 0,
                "lyrics": 0,
                "karaoke": 0,
                "forced": 0,
                "hearing_impaired": 0,
                "visual_impaired": 0,
                "clean_effects": 0,
                "attached_pic": 0,
                "timed_thumbnails": 0
            },
            "tags": {
                "language": "und",
                "handler_name": "ISO Media file produced by Google Inc.",
                "vendor_id": "[0][0][0][0]"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```